# Error downloading YouTube video using youtube-dl

Tags: macos, video, youtube, ssl

When downloading a YouTube video using `youtube-dl`, I get the following error:

```
MacBook-Pro:ytd user$ youtube-dl "https://youtu.be/dgxpBpa9A48"  
[youtube] dgxpBpa9A48: Downloading webpage  
ERROR: Unable to download webpage: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1045)> (caused by URLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1045)')))
```

What is causing this? How do I overcome it and download the video?

Comment: See if are able to open that URL in a browser window without getting any error (regarding untrusted connection or certificate).

Comment: What version are you running?  Issue the command `youbute-dl --version`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some reason `youtube-dl` has cert issues. I have always found a solution by using `--no-check-certificate` argument.

From the man page:

```
--no-check-certificate
              Suppress HTTPS certificate validation
```

Should really say "Ignores HTTPS certificate validation"...

Answer (score 1):

If you've installed Python from python.org, you need to run the `Install Certificates.command` in the Python folder in your Applications folder.

Comment: This solution fixes the problem permanently by installing certificates for Python's private copy of SSL .  The "--no-check-certificate" works as well, but must be done every time.